# Class won't serialize into JSON using unity's JSONUtility

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have the following class, which is serializable and only has strings as fields:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Cabeza
{

    string id, urlOBJ, urlTextura, pathOBJbajado, pathTexturaBajada;

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UrlOBJ { get; set; }
    public string UrlTextura { get; set; }
    public string PathOBJbajado { get; set; }
    public string PathTexturaBajada { get; set; }


    public Cabeza (string nuevoId)
    {
        Id = nuevoId;
        UrlOBJ =  nuevoId +".obj";
        UrlTextura =  nuevoId + ".png";

    }


}
```

As far I know it should be possible to obtain a JSON from it...However, JsonUtility.ToJson() returns just `{ }`. How is this possible? What am I missing?

Comment: I think it is serializing your fields, which do not have a value, and therefor not showing up in the serialization result.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `ToJson(...)`?

Comment: @Maarten UrlOBJ ad UrlTextura should have values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) mentions (but doesn't make clear) that `.ToJson()` serializes fields, not properties.

I think the following code would work as you intend:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Cabeza
{
    public string Id;
    public string UrlOBJ;
    public string UrlTextura;
    public string PathOBJbajado;
    public string PathTexturaBajada;

    public Cabeza (string nuevoId)
    {
        Id = nuevoId;
        UrlOBJ =  nuevoId +".obj";
        UrlTextura =  nuevoId + ".png";
    }
}
```